# Elementary question regarding various definitions of the integers and naturals

Tags: elementary-set-theory, integers, natural-numbers

So the question is as follows

We need to prove that $\mathbb{\mathbb{Z}}$ is the same set as the following three sets 
(i) $\{x\in\mathbb{R}\hspace{0.1cm}|\hspace{0.1cm}x\in\mathbb{\mathbb{N}}\hspace{0.1cm}or \hspace{0.1cm}x\in\mathbb{-\mathbb{N}} \hspace{0.1cm}or\hspace{0.1cm}x=0 \}$
(ii) $\{x\in\mathbb{R}\hspace{0.1cm}|\hspace{0.1cm}\exists\hspace{0.1cm}n\in\mathbb{\mathbb{N}}\hspace{0.1cm}(x+n\in\mathbb{\mathbb{N}})\}$ 
(iii) $\{x\in\mathbb{R}\hspace{0.1cm}|\hspace{0.1cm}\exists\hspace{0.1cm}n,m\in\mathbb{\mathbb{N}}\hspace{0.1cm}(m-n=x)\}$

Note: One of them can be used as a definition and we have to prove that the other two are the same set as $\mathbb{\mathbb{Z}}$

My working is as follows:

(i)
 By definition of $\mathbb{\mathbb{Z}}$.
Note: Conventionally we define natural numbers first as $ \mathbb{\mathbb{N}}=\{1,2,3,…\} $ and later integers as $\mathbb{\mathbb{Z}}=\{ x∈\mathbb{R}\hspace{0.1cm} |\hspace{0.1cm} x∈\mathbb{\mathbb{N}} ,x=0 ,x∈-\mathbb{\mathbb{N}} \}$
(ii)
 Let $x∈\mathbb{\mathbb{Z}}$ 
If, $x>0$, choose $n=0⟹x+n=x+0∈\mathbb{\mathbb{N}}$
If $x<0$, choose $n=-x+1$. Observe that $x<0⟹-x>0⟹-x+1>1>0⟹n>0$ and $x∈\mathbb{\mathbb{Z}}⟹-x+1∈\mathbb{\mathbb{Z}}⟹n∈\mathbb{\mathbb{Z}}$. Thus, $n∈\mathbb{\mathbb{N}}$ and also, $x+n=x+(-x+1)=1∈\mathbb{\mathbb{N}}$
If $x=0$, choose $n=1$ so that $x+n=0+1=1∈\mathbb{\mathbb{N}}$
Hence, $x∈$ { $x∈\mathbb{R}$ | $∃ \hspace{0.1cm}n∈\mathbb{\mathbb{N}}$ $(x+n∈\mathbb{\mathbb{N}})\}$

Let $y∈\{ x∈R \hspace{0.1cm}|\hspace{0.1cm} ∃\hspace{0.1cm} n∈\mathbb{N} (x+n∈\mathbb{N})\}$
Then, $∃ n∈\mathbb{N} (y+n∈\mathbb{N})⟹∃\hspace{0.1cm}n∈\mathbb{N}(∃\hspace{0.1cm}f∈\mathbb{N}(y+n=f))⟹∃\hspace{0.1cm}n∈\mathbb{N}(∃\hspace{0.1cm}f∈\mathbb{N}(y=f-n))⟹∃\hspace{0.1cm}m=n-f∈\mathbb{Z}(y=m)⟹y∈\mathbb{Z}$
Hence, $\mathbb{Z}=\{ x∈R | ∃ n∈\mathbb{N} (x+n∈\mathbb{N})  \}$
Note: In the last step we used part iii to write that $f-n∈\mathbb{Z}$
(iii)
 Let $x∈\mathbb{Z}$
If $x>0$, choose $m=x+1>0$ and $n=1$. Clearly by (i), $m,n∈\mathbb{Z}$
If $x=0$, choose $m=n=1$ so that $m-n=x$ with $m,n∈\mathbb{N}$
If $x<0$, choose $m=1$ and $n=-x+1>1>0$ so that $m,n∈\mathbb{N}$
Thus, $x∈\{ x∈R | ∃ m,n∈\mathbb{N} (m-n=x)  \}$

Let $y∈\{ x∈R | ∃ m,n∈\mathbb{N} (m-n=x)  \}$
Then, $∃m,n∈\mathbb{N} (m-n=y)$

As you can see, I am unable to proceed with the last conclusion. I have already used (iii) in (ii) and from the last line that I have written, I'm afraid evaluating it further would lead to circularity.

Comment: Perhaps add some blank lines in that wall of text, it's rather hard to read.

Comment: Not very clear the detail that is missing... (ii) amounts to $\exists n (x+n=m)$, for some $m$, i.e. $\exists n,m (x+n=m)$ and thus $\exists n,m (x=m-n)$

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA yes thats my point. how do you show that this is in fact the set of integers ? I already recognized that (ii) and (iii) are the same set. I just want one of them to be equal to Z

Comment: Ok; if you have already proved that (ii) and (iii) are the same set, then it is enough to show that e.g. (ii) is Z. You have (ii) subset of Z and you must show that every integer in Z is is (ii). It seems that your argument above works... If $x \ge 0$ than choose $n=0$ and $x+n$ is in (ii). If $x < 0$ then choose as $n$ the number $-x$ and $x+n=x-x=0$ is in (ii).

Comment: Wait. let me be more clear @MauroALLEGRANZA 
(ii) and (iii) are the same thing. so it is enough to prove that (ii) is Z. In my proof, I have successfully shown that Z is a subset of (ii). But for showing that (ii) is a subset of Z, I used (iii) which makes the argument circular unless you prove that (iii) is a subset of Z which I have not done and am stuck at.
So, how do you show that (ii) is a subset of Z (without using (iii)) ?